# Kotlin, генерик по умолчанию в качестве параметра функции

Tags: generics, kotlin

Есть абстрактный класс

```
abstract class Select<in T, out R>(val db: Db) {
    abstract val sql: String

    abstract fun prepare(stmt: PreparedStatement, data: T)

    abstract fun parseResult(result: ResultSet): R

    fun get(data: T): R {
        val stmt = db.connection().prepareStatement(sql)
        prepare(stmt, data)
        stmt.execute()
        return parseResult(stmt.resultSet)
    }
}
```

Есть от него наследник

```
object SelectUsers : Select<Unit, HashMap<Int, User>>(DbImpl) {
    override val sql = "SELECT usr_id, usr_name FROM users"

    override fun prepare(stmt: PreparedStatement, data: Unit) {
        return
    }

    override fun parseResult(result: ResultSet): HashMap<Int, User> {
         //не важно
    }
}
```

Ну и вызов

```
users.putAll(SelectUsers.get(Unit))
```

Собственно хочется определить для метода `get` значение по умолчанию для `data: T`. Как-то так например:

```
fun get(data: T = Unit): R //на что ругается, что логично
```

Возможно ли такое? И если да, то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге решил не изгаляться и использовать классический прием с промежуточным абстрактным классом. Заодно и определение `prepare` туда вынес.

```
abstract class SelectWithoutBind<out R>(db: Db) : Select<Unit, R>(db) {
    fun get(): R = get(Unit)

    override fun prepare(stmt: PreparedStatement, data: Unit) {
        return
    }
}

object SelectUsers : SelectWithoutBind<HashMap<Int, User>>(DbImpl) {
    override val sql = "SELECT usr_id, usr_name FROM users"

    override fun parseResult(result: ResultSet): HashMap<Int, User> {
         //не важно
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Важный момент -- откуда будет браться это значение по умолчанию?

Можно попробовать заставить `Select` его предоставлять, тогда можно это выразить такой парой функций:

```
abstract protected fun defaultT(): @UnsafeVariance T

fun get() = get(defaultT())
```

<sup>`@UnsafeVariance` тут нужно, потому что `Select` контравариантен по `T` (`in T`), и `T` нельзя типобезопасно использовать в типах возвращаемых значений. Но наружу эта функция не торчит, и единственное её использование типобезопасно,
 потому что обе функции `defaultT` и `get` вызываются на одном и том же объекте,
 а значит, для `get` фактический тип значения, которое вернёт `defaultT()`, всегда будет подтипом ожидаемого `T`.</sup>

И, соответственно, в `SelectUsers` придётся переопределить функцию:

```
override fun defaultT() = Unit
```

---

UPD: Вариант ещё лучше: если не хочется реализовывать `defaultT()` в каждом подтипе `Select`, то можно сделать отдельный интерфейс:

```
interface ProvidesDefault<T> {
    fun defaultT(): T
}
```

И `get()` с дефолтным значением оформить как extension:

```
fun <T, R, A> A.get() where A : ProvidesDefault<T>, A : Select<T, R> =
    get(defaultT())
```

Тогда реализации `Select` смогут реализовать также `ProvidesDefault<T>`, и после этого на них можно будет вызывать `get()` без параметра.

И заодно нет проблемы с вариантностью.

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил решение с отдельным интерфейсом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, варианты интересные, за что и плюсанул, но все-же пошел по более классическому пути :)